# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected embedding_1_input to have shape (150,) but got array with shape (74,)

Tags: machine-learning, word-embedding, conv-neural-network, fasttext

I am using a pretrained word vector (`fasttext`) and then running a `CNN` model. I seem to be getting a shape mismatch for the `embedding input` and `output layer`. I checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54332745/error-when-checking-input-expected-embedding-1-input-to-have-shape-4-but-got) similar question but still cannot figure out how to resolve it.

> Following is my `CNN` architecture:

```
#CNN architecture
max_seq_len =150
print("training CNN ...")
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(nb_words, embed_dim,
      weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=max_seq_len, trainable=False))
model.add(Conv1D(num_filters, 7, activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
model.add(Conv1D(num_filters, 7, activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay)))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='sigmoid'))  #multi-label (k-hot encoding)

adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

> Output:

```
training CNN ...
Model: "sequential_3"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_3 (Embedding)      (None, 150, 300)          2695800   
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_5 (Conv1D)            (None, 150, 64)           134464    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_3 (MaxPooling1 (None, 75, 64)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_6 (Conv1D)            (None, 75, 64)            28736     
_________________________________________________________________
global_max_pooling1d_3 (Glob (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 32)                2080      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 8)                 264       
=================================================================
Total params: 2,861,344
Trainable params: 165,544
Non-trainable params: 2,695,800
```

> Error because of model.fit on mismatched input and output embedding layer

```
#define callbacks
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.01, patience=4, verbose=1)
callbacks_list = [early_stopping]

#model training
hist = model.fit(word_seq_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=num_epochs, callbacks=callbacks_list, validation_split=0.1, shuffle=True, verbose=2)
```

> Error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-41-1a4b3093afeb> in <module>()
          3 callbacks_list = [early_stopping]
          4 #model training
    ----> 5 hist = model.fit(word_seq_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=num_epochs, callbacks=callbacks_list, validation_split=0.1, shuffle=True, verbose=2)

    2 frames
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
        143                             ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have shape ' +
        144                             str(shape) + ' but got array with shape ' +
    --> 145                             str(data_shape))
        146     return data
        147 

    ValueError: Error when checking input: expected embedding_3_input to have shape (150,) but got array with shape (74,)
```

Some additional info:

```
print(word_seq_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(embedding_matrix.shape)
>>(1446, 74)
>>(1446,)
>>(8986, 300)
```

Comment: word_seq_train is a seq of length 74... you have 2 possibilities: 1) set max_seq_len = 74 2) pad word_seq_train in order to put it in (1446, 150)

Answer (score 0):

From @marco's comment: using `pad_sequences` worked

```
max_seq_len =150
word_seq_train = sequence.pad_sequences(word_seq_train, maxlen=max_seq_len)
```